# No puedo instalar apache tomcat en Maco os Catalina!

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat, macos

Hola a todos quiero empezar a trabajar con aplicaciones MVC en NetBeans 8.2  y necesito instalar apache tomcat y no logro hacerlo.
se puede instalarlo por medio de Homebrew ?
alguien me puede ayudar hacerlo por terminal ?
saludos muchas gracias.

Comment: Qué error tienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La guía más simple que encontré en su momento y te recomiendo, es esta: [Installing Tomcat on macOS 10.15 Catalina](https://wolfpaulus.com/mac/tomcat/)

Está en inglés pero traduzco los pasos por encima:

1. Necesitas tener Java instalado (8 o superior; si no tienes una versión válida, recomienda instalar OpenJDK desde [este enlace](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot). En la propia web del autor hay una guía de instalación detallada de OpenJDK
2. Para agilizar el acceso a Java, el autor recomienda añadir al archivo de tu perfil *.bash_profile* la variable **JAVA_HOME**; edítalo y añade esta línea:

> ```
> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
> ```

3. Descarga Apache Tomcat. Recomienda la versión 9 desde [aquí](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi)
4. El archivo descargado estará en formato tgz; una vez descargado, descomprímelo (recomienda el uso de la app **Unarchiver**, pero eso ya a gusto de cada uno)
5. Suponiendo que descargaste la versión 9.0.35, hay que moverla a /usr/local. Abre un terminal y escribe los siguientes comandos (cambia el número de versión por el que descargaste):

> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local
> sudo mv ~/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.35 /usr/local
> ```

Te pedirá tu clave de acceso al Mac. Es normal.

6. Para facilitar la actualización con otras versiones, haremos un enlace simbólico a la versión instalada (repite estos pasos si hay otra versión)

> ```
> sudo rm -f /Library/Tomcat
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.35 /Library/Tomcat
> ```

7. Cambia el propietario del enlace simbólico:

> ```
> sudo chown -R <tu_usuario> /Library/Tomcat
> ```

8. Haz todos los scripts ejecutables:

> ```
> sudo chmod +x /Library/Tomcat/bin/*.sh
> ```

9. Puedes iniciar y parar Apache Tomcat desde la línea de comandos con:

> ```
> /Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh       (esto lo inicia)
> /Library/Tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh        (esto lo para)
> ```

10. Por último, ya puedes probar tu Apache Tomcat desde un navegador web, yendo a:

> http://localhost:8080

Comment: Buena respuesta. En general, siempre es mejor no usar instaladores para estas aplicaciones Java, configurar el JAVA_HOME y descomprimir las versiones zip